# Edge linking in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, edge-detection, hough-transform

I am trying to link the edges in images like the image below:

[image: Broken Edges]

I've tried using dilation/erosion operations but the result isn't good. Is there any other way to link the edges?

Here is the original image:

[image: Original Image]

Comment: Is this the output of an edge detection? What does the original image look like? Maybe some transformations there will make things easier.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yes, It's the output of a line detection using U-Net

Comment: Can you [edit] the image into the question?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Sure, I've added it

Comment: Please do not delete questions after receiving the answer, it can be useful for future readers. Accept the answer instead.

Answer (score 1):

The result you have might very well be good enough to apply the Hough transform to, which will identify your eight most important lines across the image.

I don't know if all your images are similar, but in the example you show it is easy to separate the gray lines from the green background. For example, the following code (using [DIPimage](https://www.diplib.org), but easy to implement with other tools too) will distinguish the relatively bright gray from anything that is dark or colorful:

```matlab
img = readim('https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmBiF.jpg');
img = colorspace(img,'hsv');
img = (0.5-img{2})*img{3}; % img{2} is the saturation channel, img{3} is the value (intensity) channel
img = clip(img);           % set negative values to 0
```

[image: output of first code snippet]

Next, a Laplace of Gaussian filter (which is a line detector), some thresholding just above zero, and a selection of only the larger objects results in the detected lines:

```matlab
img = -laplace(img,5);       % LoG with sigma=5
img = img > 0.05;            % 0.05 is just above 0
img = areaopening(img,1000); % remove objects smaller than 1000 pixels
```

[image: output of second code snippet]

Needless to say, this is a lot cheaper computationally than running a U-Net.