# Filter Binary Image to keep only the lines

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, binary-image

I have the following image [initial image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RvfS.png) and after I've converted it to binary [binary image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izyMW.png), I want in some way to keep only the 3 lines shown and remove the other objects. I've tried several things using region props etc in Matlab but I didnt manage to filter out these areas. Any idea?

Comment: The [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/object-analysis.html?s_tid=CRUX_lftnav) has tutorials for two different techniques: Hough transform and Radon transform. I'd suggest starting there.

Comment: This question cannot be answered with so little description and a single sample image. If you only have that image to process, do it by hand with an image editor ! Otherwise, the solution will depend on the properties that can be relied on from case to case. (Notice that the "objects" are also made of straight lines (though shorter).

Comment: You've deleted your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67487772/7328782) after receiving an answer. Please don't do that. It is rude and will get you question-banned. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hough transform may be the first way to refer, but in case you are not satisfied with results, you can try to use **morphological opening** with lines as structuring elements. Since your lines are directed to several different directions, you should try any possible directions and then merge yielding images. If you have a prior knowledge about directions, you can make use of it and filter by direction too.

An example code block may look like this:

```
my_img = imread('img.png'); % get your image here
opened=[];
se_length = 25; % chose in pixels, according to your need
for derece = 50:2:70 % use 0:3:180 for all directions
    se_line = strel('line', se_length, derece);
    opened = cat(3, opened, imopen(my_img, se_line));
end

max_opened = max(opened, [], 3); % merge images based on maximum (or your own method)
```

Morphological opening can be used to filter many shapes. Just select the structuring element according to your need. The above scripts give the following result for your specific image example:

[image: opened and maximized image]